# $R$ is not a principal ideal domain (show)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, solution-verification, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]=\lbrace m+n\sqrt{-17}|m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$.

How to show that $R$ is not a principal ideal domain?

My way was:

Let $I \subsetneq R$ be an ideal of $R$, given by $I= \lbrace m+n\sqrt{-17}|m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, m \equiv n$ (mod$ \ 2) \rbrace$.

Now I showed that it's not a principal ideal:

Suppose it exists an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ with $I=\langle \alpha \rangle$.

Since $2 \in I$ and $1+\sqrt{-17} \in I$, it exists $r_1,r_2 \in R$ with $2=r_1\alpha$ and $1+\sqrt{-17}=r_2\alpha$.

For the norm map $N: R \to \mathbb{N_0}$, given by $N(a+b\sqrt{-17})=a^2+17b^2$, it's $N(\alpha_1\alpha_2)=N(\alpha_1)N(\alpha_2)$

$\Rightarrow N(r_1)N(\alpha)=N(r_1\alpha)=N(2)=4$ and $N(r_2)N(\alpha)=N(1+\sqrt{-17})=18$

$\Rightarrow N(\alpha) \mid 4$ and $N(\alpha) \mid 18$

$\Rightarrow N(\alpha)=1$ or $N(\alpha)=2$

The equation $a^2+17b^2=2$ has no solutions with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$a^2+17b^2=1$ has $(a,b)=(\pm 1, 0)$ as the only solution.

$\Rightarrow \alpha= \pm 1$ and $I= \langle \pm 1 \rangle =R$, which is a contradiction.

So $I$ is not a principal ideal and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]$ is not a principal ideal domain.

Is this proof correct or is there something wrong or to improve?

Comment: Another approach uses that PIDs are UFDs. But in your ring $(1+\sqrt{-17})(1-\sqrt{-17})=2\cdot 3\cdot 3$ is a decomposition into irreducibles of the same element.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is correct (although it would be nice if you provide the proof that $I$ is indeed an ideal).

Another proof is that since $81=3^4=(8+\sqrt{-17})(8-\sqrt{-17})$, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is not a unique factorization domain (check with your norm). Hence it not a principal ideal domain.

Comment: Principal ideal domain, not "principle ideal domain".